# ADO.NET Entity Framework and WCF Service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, windows-phone-7, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a simple ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.0 model (edmx) which defines database tables with foreign key relationships.

How can I send these entities down to a Windows Phone 7 client?  I have created a WCF Service (using WShttpbinding),with the method...

```
public List<LocationCity> ListCities()
{    
   var dc = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<TestEntities>();
   var locs = dc.LocationCities.Take(10).ToList();
   return locs;
}
```

I also created a simple Console application to consume this service, but it doesn't work... In the trace I see the exception

> Maximum number of items that can be
>   serialized or deserialized in an
>   object graph is '65536'
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameterPart

I then changed MaxItemsInObjectGraph to a massive number, just to see what would happen and I get a stack overflow exception then.  So it looks to me that the dataContractSerializer is navigating cyclic properties on the object graph and getting into a recursive loop.

All I want to do is send 10 LocationCity entities down to the client (whether Windows Phone or Console).

I suppose I could create separate DataContract POCO entities, and populate them from the select on the context... however, I don't really want to have to duplicate classes for no good reason.  I figure I must be doing something wrong.

I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Have you looked at WCF RIA Services?

Comment: You ever thought about using data services?  Do you have a lot of business logic?  Or is this just a means to access a database?

Comment: There will be a lot of business logic eventually.  I haven't looked at RIA services - isn't that for Silverlight?

Comment: You dont have lazyloading enable do you?  Its disabled by default, so you should know if you do.

Comment: hmmm i thought it was disabled by default, however, it's not.  And that was the cause! thank you!

Comment: [Windows Phone 7 native apps *are* Silverlight.](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/devices/windows-phone/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had set "LazyLoadingEnabled" to true within entities designer. Just had to set it to false and everything is fine!

Answer (score 2):

The trick to deal with circular references is to use [DataContract(IsReference=true)]. IsReference property is available since .NET 3.5 SP1 so it should not be problem for you.

Best regards, Ladislav